# Cant print an variable associated to a string?

Tags: python

i was playing around with python and was wondering why i cant print a variable thats associated with a string of text, this is what i wrote.

```
name = ("martim")
print name
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why the `=` in the `print` line?

Comment: I think you've got the concept of variables backward. You should be printing `name`.

Comment: You need a tutorial, like the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

The proper way to perform what you're attempting to do is (note the comments are just to help understanding):

```
# Set name to "martin"
name = "martin"

# Print the value of name
print(name)
```

When assigning values to variables, parentheses shouldn't be used unless you're using a function for assignment; e.g., `pi = float("3.14")`. Print statements require parentheses as it is a function and the value being printed is the parameter.

Answer (score -1):

I hope these few lines will help you to understand how to use variables, values and print-statement in Python 2:

```
>>> name = "martin"
>>> print name
martin
>>> print "name"
name
>>> print "martin"
martin
```

Also you can take a look at the beginner's guide for Python: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide